# Domino Designer: Create view based on profile values

Tags: view, lotus-domino

In a Notes Application I have a (global) profile form (only one instance).
In this document there is a field containing different newsletters stored as a single string separated by commas.

On the other hand I have a form for customers.
Each customer can be nominated for some of these newsletters by a dialog list.
The code behind the choices:
`@Explode(@GetProfileField( "Profile_form";"newsletter");",")`

I want to build a view where each o´f the newsletters is a category containing the nominated customers.

I have actually no idea, how to do that. I'm quite new to Domino programming.
I tried to show the structure as follows:

```
---------- **Profile_form** --------------  
(...)  
 newsletter = "Hardware, Software"  
(...)  
-------------------------------------------
```

(Only one instance!)

---

```
---------- **Customer_form** --------------------     
name = John  
lastname = Smith  
company = Example Corporation  
newsletter_nomination = [Hardware; Software]   
-----------------------------------------------------
```

(one instance for each customer)

---

```
---------- **Newsletter_view** --------------------     
Hardware  
+---- John Smith Example Corporation  
+---- Lucy Potter Another Corporation  
Software  
+---- John Smith Example Corporation  
(...)  
----------------------------------------------------- .
```

First of all it would be very helpful for me if you can tell me how to list each newsletter as an entry within my view. If I simply select "newsletter" by the field option no entries appears in my view.

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@GetProfileField does not work in Views.

From Notes Designer Help for @GetProfileField:

> This function does not work in column, hide-when, section editor, or
>   view selection formulas. You can use it in toolbar buttons or agents.

- You can change the aplication to use regular Notes documents to store these information and these can be displayed in the view.
- If that is too complex due to dependencies on the profiles, you can write a script which creates documents which reflect the profile documents. These could be then displayed in a view.

I am not sure if the customer profiles in your application are Notes Profile documents. If I understand you correctly, I think these should be regular documents and can be displayd in a view. If that assumption is correct you can create a view which displays the customer profiles with 4 columns:

1. Column 1: newsletter_nomination field of the customer form as a categorized column
2. Column 2: lastname (flat column)
3. Column 3: name (flat column)
4. Column 4: company (flat column)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Michael, 
that sounds very good. What I gonna do is, to add an OnChange event to the "newsletter" field in order to create a document based on a new "newsletter" form for each value. But in order to not creating a document multiple times I want to check if there already exists a document with that name.

Is there a possibility to get all instances of a form in a collection?

Comment: I don't think you have to create new documents for each value. As far as I understand you want to display a list of all customers categorized by newsletter-name they have. In that case you can have a newsletter-name field on the customer form. This is a multi-value field (e. g. a checkbox). 
In the view you can display all customer forms. Create the view as described above with 4 columns - the first must be categorized and display the field newsletter_nomination => it can be expanded / collapsed. Selection of the view should be like 

'SELECT Form = "customer_form' .

Comment: Thank you very much. I gonna try this and report my results :)

Comment: Works as supposed! You're my hero :)